# Prove that $A=\{ (x,y) : xy \leq 1\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2_+$ with Euclidean Metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I wanted to ask for (part of) a proof of the above. The thing is that we have to do it proving that the complement is open, and not "skipping" any steps. I found here some proof of closedness of similar sets but often using continuity arguments or sequential arguments, but we have to prove it using the classical "if we can find for every point in the complement an open ball that is contained in the complement, then the complement is open and therefore $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x_0,y_0$ satisfy $x_0y_0 > 1$.

Let $\epsilon < {x_0y_0-1 \over |x_0|+|y_0|}$ and suppose $|x-x_0| < \epsilon, |y-y_0| < \epsilon$.

Then
\begin{eqnarray}
xy-1 &=& |x||y| -1 \\
&>&  (|x_0|-\epsilon) (|y_0|-\epsilon) -1 \\
&>& |x_0||y_0| -1 - \epsilon (|x_0|+|y_0|) \\
&>& 0
\end{eqnarray}

**Alternative**:

The function $f(x) = x_1x_2$ is continuous and the set $(1,\infty)$
is open, hence $f^{-1} ( (1, \infty))$ is open.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(x,y) = xy - 1$, and look at $A= f^{-1}((-\infty, 0])$. This is standard "argument" in point set topology and that the pre-image of a closed set is closed under continuous map. Is the set $(-\infty, 0]$ closed in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Without "skipping any steps", how do you know that $f$ is continuous?

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}_+^2$ such that $xy>1$. Take $x'\in(0,x)$ and $y'\in(0,y)$ such that $x'y'>1$. Let $\delta=\min\{x-x',y-y'\}$. Then$$a\in(x-\delta,x+\delta)\wedge b\in(t-\delta,y+\delta)\implies ab>1.$$But $D\bigl((x,y),\delta\bigr)\subset(x-\delta,x+\delta)\times(y-\delta,y+\delta)$ and therefore$$D\bigl((x,y),\delta\bigr)\subset\mathbb{R}_+^2\setminus A.$$Since this occurs for each $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}_+^2\setminus A$, $\mathbb{R}_+^2\setminus A$ is open and therefore $A$ is closed.